# Emacs config keep changing settings from '(apostrophe) to (quote) and backwards using different OS

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm using Emacs with the same config(spacemacs) on Debian & OSX computers.
This config is version controlled so each time I see the differences that git suggest to save depending on which OS I use this time.

here's an example:

```diff
-   (quote
-    ("~/gtd/inbox.org")))
+   '("~/gtd/inbox.org"))
```

Next time it is the opposite: `'` => `quote`

There are about 4 elisp forms like that in the config.

Emacs versions: 27.1 & 26.1
OS: Linux/Debian & OSX

[spacemacs config example similar to mine](https://gist.github.com/expede/b2e6b7a012053918eded#file-spacemacs-L343) - `package-selected-packages` is among ~4 settings that keep changing back and forth.

Comment: Traditionally Emacs would use `(quote x)` over `'x` so I'm guessing the newer version is no longer doing that?

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the comment. I can not fully verify it at the moment(Emacs 27 is not yet in stable apt sources) but from what I see your explanation makes perfect sense.